# Retrieve Firebase User using token, from Google Cloud application running locally

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Java API that functions as an endpoint API, and on production 
 it runs on the Google Cloud Platform. API methods are called by passing a Firebase token as part of the URL, and the token is used to create a `User` that's available inside the API method:

```
@ApiMethod(path = "myPath/{tokenId}/doSomething", httpMethod = "get")
    public ResponseMessage ReturnSomething(@Named("tokenId") String tokenId, User user) throws UnauthorizedException, BadRequestException, InternalServerErrorException, FirebaseAuthException  
    {
        if (user == null)
        ...
```

In production, when the URL is called from an Angular application on Firebase that passes the token in the URL, `user` is correctly created. I don't fully understand how the `User` is created from the token, I only know that it somehow happens "automatically" as part of Firebase integration with Google Cloud.

I want to debug the API locally by using **Debug As > App Engine** from inside Eclipse. When I do this however, and call the API from my local Angular application running using Firebase serve, the token is correctly passed to my locally running API, however `user` is always `null`.

```
@ApiMethod(path = "myPath/{tokenId}/doSomething", httpMethod = "get")
    public ResponseMessage ReturnSomething(@Named("tokenId") String tokenId, User user) throws UnauthorizedException, BadRequestException, InternalServerErrorException, FirebaseAuthException  
    {
        if (user == null)
        // this is always null
```

I suspect this is a problem with my locally running Java API correctly authenticating to Firebase. I've looked at [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional), which suggests that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` property on Windows should be set to the path of the JSON key of the App Engine default service account, which is the normal way to ensure that local access is granted to Google Cloud (and presumably Firebase) resources.

I've added this explicitly (I'd already run `gcloud auth application-default login` anyway, using the command line) however it's still not working. I just get `null` for the `user` and there's no indication of what's going on. I don't want to programatically authenticate as that means altering the API code to authenticate differently during debugging. How do I retrieve a `User` when debugging locally as App Engine?

**UPDATE**

I've realised that although the `tokenId` in the URL is present, I'm getting the following error when the API is called:

```
WARNING: Authentication failed: com.google.api.auth.UnauthenticatedException: No auth token is contained in the HTTP request
```

The `tokenId` value in the code below is a valid value, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this message:

```
@ApiMethod(path = "myPath/{tokenId}/doSomething", httpMethod = "get")
    public ResponseMessage ReturnSomething(@Named("tokenId") String tokenId, User user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this was actually a problem with the [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) library that's being used in Angular to support authenticated HTTP requests to the Java API. The Auth0 library is used to inject the auth token into the `Bearer` of the request header whenever an Angular `http.get` is called from the Angular application. Creation of the `User` depends on this property being present *in the HTTP header*, with its value set to the value of the auth token.

I fixed this by altering the config for this library. I needed to temporarily whitelist `localhost` for the port (8080) that the API runs on, to allow Auth0 to inject the token into the HTTP header whenever there is a request to `localhost:8080`

```
const jwtConf: JwtModuleOptions = {
  config: {
    tokenGetter: getToken,
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:8080']
  }
};
```